# Given a latitude and longitude, Get the location name

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am developing an application wherein I get the latitude, longitude in my android device and post them to a web server.

and in a web application I show the location details with the help of google maps.

Here I have huge collection of lat long values which i loop it in my jsp and create multiple markers with info windows.

Now the problem is that I need to show the location name of the particular latitude and longitude in the Info Window of google maps.

Can anyone help me with the google maps script or how can i get the location name from the lat long values in my android phone itself, so that I can post that to my web server.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here i am given a single just pass the latitude and longitude in this function then you got all the information related to this latitude and longitude.

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is GUIStatics, how to solve this error :--> GUIStatics cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: he is right, mahn :/ we need full codes and explanation here :(

Comment: Guys who are not understanding this code, first get your Latitude and Longitude and then pass these values in this Method and you will get all the Information about your Location, here is the link where you can find the longitude and latitude..
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/
Kindly comment the GUIStatistics if you don't need. I don't need that so I just remove and get my Placemark Information.

Answer (score 7):

```
Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(yourContext, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude),Double.parseDouble(longitude), 1);
Address address = (Address) myList.get(0);
String addressStr = "";
addressStr += address.getAddressLine(0) + ", ";
addressStr += address.getAddressLine(1) + ", ";
addressStr += address.getAddressLine(2);
```

Comment: here just find lat long from this code, LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);  
     double m=location.getLatitude();
     double n=location.getLongitude();

Answer (score 5):

```
StringBuilder _homeAddress = null;
        try{
            _homeAddress = new StringBuilder();
            Address address = null;
            List<Address> addresses = _coder.getFromLocation(_lat,_lon,1);
            for(int index=0; index<addresses.size(); ++index)
            {
                address = addresses.get(index);
                _homeAddress.append("Name: " + address.getLocality() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Sub-Admin Ares: " + address.getSubAdminArea() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Admin Area: " + address.getAdminArea() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Country: " + address.getCountryName() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Country Code: " + address.getCountryCode() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Latitude: " + address.getLatitude() + "\n");
                _homeAddress.append("Longitude: " + address.getLongitude() + "\n\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `android.location.geocoder.getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)`

it will give you a list of addresses.

Answer (score 3):

```
   private String getAddress() {
        GPSTracker   gps = new GPSTracker(ProductList.this);
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ProductList.this, Locale.getDefault());
        String address="";
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), 1);
            Address obj = addresses.get(0);
            String  add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
//optional
          /*  add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
            add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();*/

            Log.e("Location", "Address" + add);
            address=add;
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return address;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(DistaceCalculating.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                Address obj = addresses.get(0);
                String   add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
                String  currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                        + obj.getAdminArea();
                double   latitude = obj.getLatitude();
                double longitude = obj.getLongitude();
                String currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
                String currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
               add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
                add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();
    
                
                System.out.println("obj.getCountryName()"+obj.getCountryName());
                System.out.println("obj.getCountryCode()"+obj.getCountryCode());
                System.out.println("obj.getAdminArea()"+obj.getAdminArea());
                System.out.println("obj.getPostalCode()"+obj.getPostalCode());
                System.out.println("obj.getSubAdminArea()"+obj.getSubAdminArea());
                System.out.println("obj.getLocality()"+obj.getLocality());
                System.out.println("obj.getSubThoroughfare()"+obj.getSubThoroughfare());
    
                
                Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```