# Get location name from fetched coordinates

Tags: android, location

**What i have:** currently my app is only telling me the coordinates of my current location.

**What i want:** Get location name from coordinates fetched by gps, so that i could know where exactly i am. (Name of location)

Comment: are you looking for this '[given-a-latitude-and-longitude-get-the-location-name][1]'


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172451/given-a-latitude-and-longitude-get-the-location-name

Comment: Have a look at [How To Program Google Android](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-12-15-n14.html)

Comment: Your question is same as the question I posted a few months back..check this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172451/given-a-latitude-and-longitude-get-the-location-name or check my answer below...

Comment: @Krishna yes i have seen it but the answers given to ur question were not dat much easy so i decided ti put mine.

Comment: @Sam Quest.. answers given there are not that much understood by me.

Comment: @Noman.. almost all of us have said the same thing. The Geocoder class in the googles map api kit gives location details like Place name, address, etc.

Comment: **android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults)**, Returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is complete code from fetching long - lat to getting address:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){                 
double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
        String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: Sometimes this reverse Geocoding technique does not give any address.So How to get Address from lat-long every time whenever I need???

Comment: yes, It does not return the address sometime. For this you can implement a back up mechanism like when you don't get the address you hit it again to get the address or you can use google api to get the address.

Comment: use this permissions : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I am getting Location always null!

Answer (score 7):

You can us the `GeoCoder` which is available in android.location.`Geocoder` package. The  [JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) gives u full explaination. The possible sample for u.

```
 List<Address> list = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location
                .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (list != null & list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            result = address.getLocality();
            return result;
```

The `result` will return the name of the location.

Answer (score 6):

Here i am given a single just pass the latitude and longitude in this function then you got all the information related to this latitude and longitude.

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I hope you get the solution to your answer.

Comment: how can i get the exact location of my place, it gives max the city value, i want the locaation name inside city