# Get country from coordinates?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps

How to get country name in Android, If are known geo coordinates? How to make it the simplest way?

Comment: There are several ways of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922312/get-location-name-from-fetched-coordinates

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Below Function for that.

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Add Below Permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Your code got a bug. Sometimes, from the `lat` and `lng`, you got no address. Which means `address.get(0)` raises `IndexOutOfBound` exception.

Comment: I would a faster way to get just country code (I don't need the full address), but here `Geocoder` works slow

Answer (score 32):

Here you go

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

    if (addresses.size() > 0)
     {  
       String countryName=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
try {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
            placeName.setText("Waiting for Location");
        }
        else {
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                placeName.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() +", " + addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Location Name Found", 600).show();
    }
```

use this in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

How I did it recently was to read the data from the Web API URL and parse the JSON.

An example URL for the point(40.714224, -73.961452) is:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=40.714224,-73.961452&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=true_or_false&key=your_api_key
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{
  "name": "40.714224,-73.961452",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "285 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 8,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "NY",
         "SubAdministrativeArea" : {
            "Locality" : {
               "DependentLocality" : {
                  "DependentLocalityName" : "Williamsburg",
                  "PostalCode" : {
                     "PostalCodeNumber" : "11211"
                  },
                  "Thoroughfare" : {
                     "ThoroughfareName" : "285 Bedford Ave"
                  }
               },
               "LocalityName" : "Brooklyn"
            },
            "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "Kings"
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "USA",
      "CountryNameCode" : "US"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 40.7154779,
        "south": 40.7127799,
        "east": -73.9600584,
        "west": -73.9627564
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -73.9614074, 40.7141289, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

I find GSON to be quite good for parsing JSON in Android.