# Get location name based on given Coordinate in Windows Mobile

Tags: vb.net, geolocation, gps, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing Windows Mobile apps using vb.net. And Currently, I managed to get the coordinate, but how to get **Location name** of the **fetched coordinate**?

I found  [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922448/2817802) for android, but I can't found any reference for Windows mobile/vb.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a location name for a geoloocation coordinate you need access to a GIS system like Google MAPS. You can use google API to query information about geo coordinates: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

An alternative to google location API is at geonames.org. But you have to start coding or your own web service client (as with google location API). For .net start at http://www.geonames.org/export/client-libraries.html.

You may also use other web services to ask about such information.
Without internet access you may need a navigation software with SDK to provide you information about a coordinate, for example ALK navigation and it's SDK.

Comment: means I must have an Internet connection to get the location name?

Comment: Yes, or a large database like provided by a navigation app as already stated.