# Get location name from fetched coordinates get the name

Tags: android, gps, location

I have found this solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922312/get-location-name-from-fetched-coordinates) to get the location name but I don't know how to display it in my `textView`:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){                 
double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());                 
try {
    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
        String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    t.append("\n " + ????? + " ");
}

}
```

The t is the `textView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the name address in the String `_Location`. Therefore, you could set the value of `TextView` in the try block.

```
try { 
List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
    String _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
} 
t.setText(_Location);
}
```

**Further Infomation**

```
    String address1 = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = listAddresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state = listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    String knownName = listAddresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

    t.setText(address1 + " " + city + "\n" + state + " " + postalCode);
```

You could use this code to get further information about the adress